# Style of the site depending off the season

Tags: css, html

Hi i am working on a site for a friend. She wants to use a different style sheet for each season; one for winter, spring, summer and fall.

I was thinking about the following approach...
I've build the site using a style.css for each season, now all I have to do is load the appropriate style.css for the period of time of year.

But how to do that?

Comment: you will have to use a server side language like php in order to do some check of the date and call the appropiate css

Comment: @Matías No you don't have to do that

Comment: @scrblnrd3, well no; it doesn't have to be server-side, but there has to be something done (client-, or server-, side) to detect the season, and that's done by assessing the date. But regardless, this isn't possible without either JavaScript or some server-side solution (whatever might be chosen or available).

Comment: Yeah, you could use javascript's Date() or moment.js

Comment: @scrblnrd3 What if the users have javascript disabled?

Comment: Probably the best is to go with server side scripting to prevent abrupt changes as the page is rendering. You can load a different css file or have all the styling in one css file and just set a class (with i.e. the season name) on the body element.

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to use PHP because the user may have javascript disabled.

This would be my approach:

PHP:

```
//season.php file
header("Content-type: text/css");

function getSeason()
{
    $season_dates = array('/12/21'=>'winter',
                        '/09/21'=>'autumn',
                        '/06/21'=>'summer',
                        '/03/21'=>'spring',
                        '/12/31'=>'winter');

    foreach ($season_dates as $key => $value) // Loop through the season dates
    {
        $season_date = date("Y").$key;
        if (strtotime("now") > strtotime($season_date)) // If we're after the date of the starting season
        {
           return $value;
        }
   }
}

$season = getSeason();

echo file_get_contents("$season.css");
```

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="season.php">
```

Comment: This approach is short. I like that.
But it doesn't seem to work. I made the php file. and linked it in the html. like suggested Am I missing something?

Comment: see edit: try adding `header("Content-type: text/css");`

Answer (score 1):

You could use alternative stylesheets

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="summer" href="summer.css">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="spring" href="spring.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="fall" href="fall.css">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="winter" href="winter.css">
```

And then create a script

```
function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
   var links=document.getElementsByTagName("link");
   for(var i=0; i<styles.length; i++) {
     style=styles[i];
     if(style.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && style.getAttribute("title")) {
       style.disabled = true;
       if(style.getAttribute("title") == title){
          style.disabled = false;
       }
     }
   }
}
```

And then to detect the season, you can use

```
var month=new Date().getMonth();
if(month<2 || month==11){
    setActiveStyleSheet("winter");
}else if(month<5){
    setActiveStyleSheet("spring");
}else if(month<8){
    setActiveStyleSheet("summer");
}else if(month<11){
    setActiveStyleSheet("fall");
}
```

Obviously, you can make the season selection more accurate, but that will give you at least a rudimentary season

Comment: Thanx.. that is fast
I wil look into that option. Thanx again.

Comment: This one works until the part where he seems to select the summer.css  Am I missing something?

Comment: Do I have tot test this in the webdomein? or should this also work offline?